# Remove <ul> and <li> but keep content

Tags: jquery

I have the following html code and would like to remove the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags but keep the content.

```
<div class="test">
  <ul>
    <li> some text here</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So i would like the result to be

```
<div class="test">
   some text here
</div>
```

Can i do this with jQuery?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: *"Can i do this with jQuery?"* Yes. Have a look through [the API](http://api.jquery.com), take a stab at it, and if you get stuck on something specific, ask about that specific thing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP could solve this problem very little research himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the contents of the `li` as markup with the `html` function, or just text with the `text` function; then replace the contents of the `div` with just that markup/text:

```
 // save text
 text = $('.test li').html(); // or .text()

 // remove the ul
 $('.test ul').remove();

 // append the text to the div.test
 $('.test').append(text)
```

Comment: This worked great for me. Thanks. Was first time posting for me here, so got the formatting wrong. :(

Comment: @rkuiper: If this (or another answer here) *answered* your question, the way SO works, you'd "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: @rkuiper: Note that this will keep (well, recreate) elements (not just text) if they're *within* the `li`s, e.g. `<li><span>foo</span></li>`. If you don't want that, start with `.text()` rather than `.html()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2uLtd9w/)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var elem=$(".test");
    var content=elem.text();
    elem.empty();
    elem.text(content);
    });
```

Comment: There's zero reason to do `.empty()` on something you're about to call `.text(...)` on.

Answer (score 1):

Can use `html(function)` approach:

```
$(".test").html(function(){
    return $(this).find('li').html();
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ftvv4bry/)**</kbd>